# Different forms of addressing parents

Tags: translation, politeness, vocatives, forms-of-address

In my language there is an older form in which you use kinship term in the middle of a sentence, in which normally you would use "you". Here's how this would look translated to English

Normal -> "Dad, why do you think it's a bad idea?" (second person)

Older form -> "Why does Dad think it's a bad idea?" (third person)

They both mean the same thing in my native language. My question is, does the second form actually exist in English as a form to refer *to* your dad *while* talking *with* him?

Comment: It wouldn't be wrong grammatically, but it sounds extremely patronising unless the father needs addressing in 'kiddispeak' because he is suffering for dementia, say. Though one could switch from addressing mum say to dad mid-sentence using these words.

Comment: I am not familiar with any such usage in English. I can imagine, in a pinch, someone speaking that way in a kind of affectionate, ironic twist, but that usage would not be specific to family members. If it isn't indiscrete to ask, would you mind telling us what your native language is? It would be interesting to know where this is a custom.

Comment: @IsabelArcher I'm form Poland, but as I said, it's an old form, nowadays only used towards older people (for example to grandmother if you're not very close). It's seen as impolite, in my language, to use "you" towards someone if you're not close to them (even if they're family) or if they should be shown respect (as teachers, which I believe can be referred to as "you" in English)

Comment: Thanks, @user385889. That's interesting. As you know, English doesn't have a lot of the distinctions between formal and familiar forms of "you" that so many other languages have. Obviously there are ways of making the distinction, but they are not cut and dry and depend greatly on a speaker's creativity. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @IsabelArcher - I think you meant "If it isn't indiscreet to ask".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, indeed I did. Thanks for pointing it out. Changing it now. Actually, no, I'm not, because the site now won't let me edit my own comment. Please consider it changed, and thank you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - re third-person 'kiddispeak', or [illeism](https://www.fatherly.com/health-science/why-parents-talk-to-kids-third-person-illeism/) - as a child, and as a parent, I have always found the practice distasteful and annoying. "Mummy doesn't want you to make a mess with your toys", "Daddy doesn't like Johnny banging on the window", etc. [Nick Luxmoore](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/young-people-close/201201/you-and-i-and-him-and-me) in _Psychology Today_ seems to agree with me.

Comment: @IsabelArcher I have found the only way to 'edit' a comment after the five-minute time window is to copy it into your clipboard, delete it, and re-post the edited version. Of course this might spoil chronology and lose any comment upvotes it has gained, but these are ephemeral anyhow.

Comment: "What do _you_ think, dad?" is about as normal as it gets. (ie totally standard and acceptable)

Comment: If you were going to do it you should say "father", not "dad".

Comment: Well, it would be customary and respectful to *speak in the third person* when addressing royalty, though not parents. Does Her Highness disagree?

Comment: I learned Swedish for a year when I was at university nearly 50 years ago. It was then considered polite to address people you didn't know well in the third person (I don't think this included family members, though). Judging from the Swedish TV dramas I've seen recently, the practice appears to have died out.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - "The official website for the British Monarchy states "there are no obligatory codes of behaviour when meeting the Queen or a member of the Royal Family" - BBC

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes, thanks.

Comment: Italian has a special set of personal pronouns meant only for royalty, or, these days, the President of the Republic, _Loro_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the second form when talking to your dad if you were being sarcastic or meaning it in another humorous way, but only if your tone indicated humour and was understood by your dad.

Without that understanding it would most likely come across as rude and patronising. In normal conversations you would always use the first form.

Comment: This has already been said; to include it in an 'answer' (I'm not sure the question belongs on ELU myself), reasonable research showing that this is not purely opinion should be shown.